# How to navigate to next sqlite table column in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am noob to android and sqlite, in visual basic working with access database you get a active x control or adodc control which helps to navigate through next records . Iam developing a app for android which i need to require to select the next column in press of button click.

ie, 
Sql lite database

table1
column1, column2, column3

the preceding is the structure of table 
i have a text view which displays the column name . if i press the button if column1 is selected the column2 should be displayed.

i have no idea on how to code .

prompt Help is appreciated

Comment: Will you be displaying only one column at a time?

Comment: You access data via `Cursor` which has those `moveToXYZ` methods to move rows and e.g. `Cursor.getString(int columnIndex)` to get columns of the active row.

Answer (score 0):

1. Query your data via a [cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)
2. Populate that data into an object (any sort of Collection or
   custom pojo) within your activity.
3. Write a [clickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) for your button which takes in a 'current column'
   value.  The clickListener can then grab the corresponding 'next column' from the object you saved the data to.
4. The clickListener will then update your UI